# How do I convert a string which is actually a date with timezone to a timestamp in Presto?

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, presto

Example : 2017-12-24 23:59:59.000 PST

This does not work

```
select date_parse('2017-12-24 23:59:59.000 PST','%Y-%m-%d %T.%f %x')
```

Sure I can truncate the TZ which will solve

```
select date_parse(substr('2017-12-24 23:59:59.000 PST',1,23),'%Y-%m-%d %T.%f')
```

Is there a way to do this without truncating the TZ ?

Answer (score 3):

`date_parse` doesn't seem to support time zones, use [`parse_datetime`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions) instead:

```
presto> select parse_datetime('2017-12-24 23:59:59.000 PST', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z');
                    _col0
---------------------------------------------
 2017-12-24 23:59:59.000 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```

Comment: Here's the new link to the docs, https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions

Comment: Actually the updated link is https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions (prestosql.io moved to trino.io). For Athena, https://trino.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions could be used, but the content is the same for this function, so doesn't matter.