# Can you use a column for the timezone parameter of AT TIME ZONE in Presto / Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Here is an operation you can perform in Athena-

```
SELECT date_utc AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
FROM
(
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-09-09 12:00:00' as date_utc

) x;
```

In other sql engines you can change `America/Chicago` to a column-

```
SELECT date_utc AT TIME ZONE x.timezone
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2018-09-09 12:00:00' as date_utc,
    'America/Chicago' as timezone

) x;
```

In Athena you get-

> line 1:30: no viable alternative at input 'time zone x'

Should it be possible to use `x.timezone` in Athena? This seems like a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string which is actually a date with timezone to a timestamp in Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070592/how-do-i-convert-a-string-which-is-actually-a-date-with-timezone-to-a-timestamp)

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Don't believe so

Comment: sorry, wrong link; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230931/prestodb-sql-changing-time-zones-using-time-zone-string-coming-as-a-result-of ; However, I find @jenswalter answer much nicer than what i wrote there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It indeed looks like a bug in the engine. What is interesting however is, that the underlying function works with a column parameter. So you can use this as a workaround.

```
SELECT at_timezone(date_utc,x.timezone)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2018-09-09 12:00:00' as date_utc,
    'America/Chicago' as timezone

) x;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was worried the question was going to be too niche to get responses and the aws forums themselves are a crap shoot

Answer (score 3):

Adding some additional context to the the correct answer above:
`AT_TIMEZONE` function is not documented in presto docs. When someone uses `timestamp AT time zone tz` , its actually `AT_TIMEZONE` function that gets called. It appears to be an internal function, which some folks were already using. Here is an issue discussing it: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5162

The syntax appears to be `AT_TIMEZONE(date_field, tz_field_or_string)`