# PrestoDB dynamic timezone conversions using AT TIME ZONE operator

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

How to pass dynamic timezone to AT TIME ZONE operator in prestodb query? Idea is to convert each row timestamp to different timezones based on the joining table.

Below query throws error

```
WITH time_zones as (
  SELECT 'America/Los_Angeles' as time_zone
)

SELECT timestamp '2012-10-31 01:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE time_zone
FROM time_zones
```

Error

```
line 5:54: no viable alternative at input 'time zone time_zone' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: )
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52446806/2958751

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use a column for the timezone parameter of AT TIME ZONE in Athena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446184/can-you-use-a-column-for-the-timezone-parameter-of-at-time-zone-in-athena)

Comment: using function at_timezone works. Thank you